# Can't add reference to HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, silverlight, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

I created an empty application (SilverLight for Windows Phone) that should parse a web page. i added a reference (NuGet) to HtmlAgilityPack. I added the using statement, but it says that it can't find it.
Why? I didn't have this problem with Windows Phone 8 application.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. Are you able to install HtmlAgilityPack at all or are you getting an error when installing via nuget? Please provide the error message and we can help you some more.

Comment: Nuget doesn't say anything and it doesn't add anything in the reference directory. And then i get the usual error you get when you didn't put the using statement at the beginning.

Comment: Ah, I had an issue adding html agility pack to a solution this morning. However, when I attempted it did give me an error. I solved the issue by updating nuget. I would suggest that you update nuget and try it again if you haven't already.

Comment: I can't find how to update NuGet...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same on all versions of VS but on VS 2010 go to tools -> Extension Manager. A new window will pop up and on the Extension Manager click the updates tab in the left pane. It will check for updates and any available updates to the installed extension will be shown in the center pane. It is likely that it will have more than one update available so just look for nuget and update that. Once the update is complete, restart VS.

Comment: NuGet was already updated. So i installed it again and now it seems to work. Thank you.